# Unable to launch http://homestead.app after all setup of homestead done

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am newbie for homestead. I done all setup of homestead with VitualBox and Vagrant. After Vagrant up I got following message in terminal:

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default: 
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.1
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /home/prabhu
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

But still unable to get launch homestaed.app or getting any error.
Please help.

Comment: Did you map `homestead.app` to `127.0.0.1` in your `hosts` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me assume you are on Linux or Mac,
If so, you have to "route" homestead.app to your machine.

That's done editing /etc/hosts and adding this line:

```
192.168.10.10    homestead.app
```

By default homestead uses `192.168.10.10` for the machine, so it should work.

---

EDIT:

Create a new project in the virtual machine

- Do `vagrant ssh` in your homestead folder to connect to the machine with ssh
- Do `composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name`

Then, be sure to link your project folder with a project folder in the virtual machine.

Check that you have this on your Homestead.yaml

```
folders:
- map: ~/your-project-folder
  to: /home/vagrant/your-project-folder
```

Where `map` is your local folder and `to` is the folder that will be created in the virtual machine.

Then, edit your Homestead.yaml and create a new `site` for your project, mine looks like that

```
 sites:                                                                        
  - map: development.app                                                    
    to: /home/vagrant/plannerking/public                                    
  - map: vetur.app                                                          
    to: /home/vagrant/vetur/public                                          
  - map: mailprocess.app                                                    
    to: /home/vagrant/mailprocess/public
```

And finally, write in `/etc/hosts` the name of your new project `ex: mailprocess.app` and route it to the virtual machine.

```
192.168.10.10    mailprocess.app
```

Everything is great explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead)

Comment: My OS is  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Above setting done host file but still facing same issue.

Comment: I am getting in Chrome browser following things whenever trying to access http://homestead.app : 

This site can’t be reached

homestead.app took too long to respond.

Answer (score -1):

Dont use gTLD domain extensions like `.app`, use `.test`, `.local` etc

Comment: Please edit your answer and add explanation, why those gTLD shouldn't be used?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768289/chrome-redirects-dev-to-https